# extract a file from xz file

Tags: tar, xz

I have a huge file `file.tar.xz` containing many smaller text files with a similar structure. I want to quickly examine a file out of the compressed file and have a glimpse of files content structure. I don't have information about names of the files within the compressed file. Is there anyway to extract a single file out given the above the above scenario?

Thank you.

EDIT: I don't want to `tar -xvf file.tar.xz`.

Comment: extract it using what? shell? C?

Comment: if possible using the bash tar

Comment: Do you already know the path/name of the file you want to extract out of the archive?

Comment: I know the path but not the name of the file

Comment: how would you know then what to extract? I have no idea what you want to achieve, you should provide a more detailed example of your problem.

Comment: I have a 2TB archive and I want to pull out a single file to examine the structure of a file. On the basis of which I will write a program which will process the whole archive eventually.

Comment: you just want to extract any single file out of the structure? It does not matter which?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, I tried the following which worked for me. It might not be the most optimal solution, the regex might need some improvement, but you'll get the idea.

I first created a demo archive:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir demo
for i in {1..100}; do echo $i > "demo/$i.txt"; done
cd demo && tar cfJ ../demo.tar.xz * && cd ..
```

`demo.tar.xz` now contains 100 txt files.

The following lists the contents of the archive, selects the first file and stores the path within the archive into the variable `firstfile`:

```
 firstfile=`tar -tvf demo.tar.xz | grep -Po  -m1  "(?<=:[0-9]{2} ).*$"`
```

`echo $firstfile` will output `1.txt`.

You can now extract this single file from the archive:

```
tar xf demo.tar.xz $firstfile
```

Comment: No, it didn't work for me. `echo $firstfile` spits nothing and when I remove the space between `" .`  `echo $firstfile` holds a value but I `tar` it I get file `Not found in archive` error. Try creating a random archive out of five files from your hard drive and see if the method is transferable. Thanks though.

Comment: @TadeleT: I updated the regex, worked for me for various files.